# Этимология слова "взять".

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Есть однокоренные слова у слова "взять"?

Comment: Виктория! Вопрос подразумевает хотя бы знак вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание)

Answer (score 2):

**Однокоренные:** `взятка`, `взятие`, `взяточник`, `взяточнический`, `взяточничество`, `взяться`.

**Этимология:** произошло от праславянского *jьmǫ : jęti, от которого в том числе произошли `имѣти`, `имамь`, а также `възѩти`, `възьмѫ`. Отсюда `взять`, `снять`, `изъять` и другие приставочные глаголы на `-нять/-ять` `(-емлю)`.

Comment: Однокоренные... А общий-то корень какой?